# Is the word 'outside' a preposition or a noun in this context?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

In the sentence 'The outside of the folder got wet,' is the word 'outside' a preposition or a noun? How do you decide if a particular area is described, a preposition becomes a noun? For example, in 'on the playground', 'on' is a preposition. Here again, it refers to a particular area. I have been through many sites, but none with a proper explanation of how the preposition turns into a noun in these contexts.

Comment: Compare with 'The top of the fridge got wet.'

Comment: Example 10 from [learnamericanenglishonline.com](https://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Prepositions/outside.html) *The **outside** of a peach is fuzzy and a little thick; the inside is sweet and juicy.* In this sentence, "outside" is used a noun: *"**The** outside..."*

Comment: Outside of a dog, a book is a man's best friend. Inside of a dog it's too dark to read.

Answer (score 4):

*’Twas brillig, and the slithy toves

              Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:

        All mimsy were the borogoves,

              And the mome raths outgrabe.*

It sounds like you think that a word “is” some part of speech, and that it can therefore “turn” into another one. That isn’t quite how it works, although the concept of *zero derivation* is when you use a word in a different grammatical way without any change to the form.

Many *-side* words in English began life as compound words: *alongside, aside, beside, broadside, dayside, fireside, hillside, inside, mountainside, nightside, offside, otherside, outside, overside, southside, topside, trailside, underside, wayside, woodside, yonside* are just a few of them.

When the word that *-side* was attached to began life as a noun, the result usually did, too, but when the original word began life as an adverb, so too the result — at first. Then some of the whilom adverbs started to be used as prepositions or as nouns, or as both.

Here's an example that uses *outside* as five different parts of speech, which you can tell because of the syntax (word order) and inflectional morphology (endings):

> 1. If you go outside<sup>*(adverb)*</sup>,
> 2. you’ll see that the outside<sup>*(adjective)*</sup> buildings,
> 3. meaning the ones outside<sup>*(preposition)*</sup> the perimeter,
> 4. aren’t so well maintained on their outsides<sup>*(noun)*</sup> as they are on their insides.
> 5. This shows that they haven’t been outsided<sup>*(verb)*</sup> well enough.

You know what the parts of speech are up there in that sample passage for the same reason you know what they are in Carroll. It’s the grammar that matters. You should go through each of those five examples and look at the many clues pointing you towards each one’s part of speech.

As with all things grammatical, that means you need to look at syntax and morphology. I’ll let you use the same skills on my example as are needed on your own.

> The outside of the folder got wet.

In your example, because the predicate is “got wet”, then you know that the subject is “the outside of the folder”, and that means it has to be a noun phrase of some sort. That *outside* there **MUST** be a noun in *the outside of the folder* because it’s got a determiner *the* in front of it and there’s no other parse that leaves a valid subject.

Prepositional phrases can be deleted from a sentence without changing the grammaticality of the sentence. If *outside of* were a two-word preposition whose object were *the folder*, then we could delete the whole thing:

> The <s>outside of the folder</s> got wet. 
>   ✱The got wet.

We can't do that, because "The got wet" is not grammatical. Therefore *outside of the folder* is not here a prepositional phrase.

But what about *of the folder*? Can we delete that safely?

> The outside <s>of the folder</s> got wet.
>   The outside got wet.

Yes, we can. That one is ok, which means that *outside* is here a noun.

It is easily possible to construct a version where *outside* really is a preposition though.

> Outside of the folder, the papers got wet.

Now *outside of* really  is a two-word preposition, not a noun plus a preposition. You know this because it’s the only valid parse.

Comment: So the parse tells you the parts of speech.  Right on.

Comment: @GregLee Do you have a better model for explaining my own example's POS assignments, let alone Jabberwocky's? Syntax is part of it, but the morphology is as well.

Comment: Include the morphological structure as part of the parse, I suppose.

Comment: tchrist, Thank you very much. Your explanation was quite clear.